# How to search and replace a horizontal rule and linebreaks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I need to automatically delete all horizontal rules which are surrounded by 6 linebreaks (3 before and 3 after) on a google doc.

This piece of code seems to put in the logs the correct linebreaks I want to delete (that's a first step) :

```js
function myFunction() {
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody().getText();
var pattern = /\s\s\s\s/g; 
  while (m=pattern.exec(body)) { Logger.log(m[0]); }
}
```

I have two questions :

- What tool can I use to delete these linebreaks (I don't yet understand the subtilies of using replace or replaceText, all my attemps with these have failed) ?
- How can I add to my var pattern (the pattern to be deleted) a horizontal rule ? I tried /\s\s\s\sHorizontalRule\s\s\s\s/g but of course it did not work.

Comment: Soft break(\r) or hard break(\n)?

Comment: hard break (\n), made with the enter key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Horizontal rule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/horizontal-rule) is an element inside a paragraph (or sometimes inside a list item). Since it is not text, it can not be found or replaced by means of a regular expression. We should search for objects which are specially arranged in the document body, and delete them if found.

Consider the following code example:

```
function deleteHR() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var hr = null, hrArray = [], countDeleted = 0;

  // Collect all horizontal rules in the Document
  while (true) {
    hr = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.HORIZONTAL_RULE, hr);
    if (hr == null) break;
    hrArray.push(hr);
  }

  hrArray.forEach(function(hr) {
    var p = hr.getElement().getParent();
    // Get empty paragraphs as siblings (if any)
    var prevSiblings = getSiblings(p, 3, true),
        nextSiblings = getSiblings(p, 3, false);
    // Define a short function for batch deleting items
    function remove(e) {
      e.removeFromParent();
    }
    // If empty paragraphs exist (3 before and 3 after)
    if (prevSiblings.length == 3 && nextSiblings.length == 3) {
      // then delete them as well as the rule itself
      hr.getElement().removeFromParent();
      prevSiblings.forEach(remove);
      nextSiblings.forEach(remove);
      countDeleted++;
    }
  });
  // Optional report
  Logger.log(countDeleted + ' rules deleted');
}


// Recursive search for empty paragraphs as siblings
function getSiblings(p, n, isPrevious) {
  if (n == 0) return [];
  if (isPrevious) {
    p = p.getPreviousSibling();
  } else {
    p = p.getNextSibling();
  }
  if (p == null) return [];
  if (p.getType() != DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) return [];
  if (p.asParagraph().getText().length > 0) return [];
  var siblings = getSiblings(p, n - 1, isPrevious);
  siblings.push(p);
  return siblings;
}
```

Main function `deleteHR()` does all the work. However it appears helpful to use another separate function `getSiblings()` for recursive search for empty paragraphs. May be, this way is not the only, but it works.

Comment: Thank you very much, there are a lot of things new to me here so I can't get my head around everything you did. But I tried to just get one horizontal rule deleted with this code : 
`function deleteOneHR() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  hr = null;  hrArray = [];
  
    hr = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.HORIZONTAL_RULE, hr);
  hr.getElement().removeFromParent();
  Logger.log(hr);
 
}`
There is no error shown, the log shows RangeElement, but the only one horizontal line within my document will not get deleted. I don't know why.

Comment: I can not check your doc, but the code above really deletes hr from my doc.

Comment: Well, oddly I've created a new document and now your big code works perfectly, as well as my small code in my comment (I guess  I did not point to the correct document the code was executing on, maybe). Thank you very much !